# Different leading and trailing spacing for 5/5S/6 and 6 Plus

Tags: iphone, xcode, autolayout, xcode6

I have 3 buttons in my view that I want to be distributed horizontally - first button 5% (approx) from the left edge, second button 5% from that button, third button 5% from that button and 5% from the right edge. I have it like that on the 4S, 5 and 5S:

**4S, 5, 5S:**
[image: 5S buttons]

but on the 6 Plus the left and rightmost buttons stay 5% from the edges and the middle button is spaced out too much from the other two:

**6 Plus:**
[image: 6 Plus buttons]

Is there a way I can have different spacing for the leading and trailing edges only on the 6 Plus? The Width Compact, Height Regular size class seems to affect all portrait iPhones.

**Edit:** Solved, see answer below.

Comment: Could this be because of the different pixel densities of the different displays?

Comment: It's because the 6 Plus has more horizontal pixels than the 4S/5/5S. I set a 20px margin from the left and right and this looked OK on 4 inch screens, but the 6 Plus on retaining this 20px margin resulted in more than 20px between those buttons and the middle button. I was ideally looking for a way to have different trailing and leading margins for the 6 Plus, but the solution I just added also works.

Comment: Glad you go it fixed, i haven't done much ios dev but in Android it's standard practice to have multiple of the same image, each at a different ppi, then when the assets are loaded you get the correct sized image for that display, which would mean your 5% spacing would remain consistent across devices

Comment: It works similar for iOS, you have 1x, 2x and 3x images. I want the button size to remain at 86pt (172px on 4S-6, 258px on 6 Plus), and there's no easy way to evenly distribute items across the screen.

Comment: Interesting, I'm developing an ios app for my final year uni project if I run into a similar problem and find another solution that doesn't require a spacing hack I'll let you know.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by placing 20px wide separator views (which can be white, clear, hidden, etc) between each button and on the left and right sides of the superview. The leftmost view has these constraints:
- 0px margin from the top and left edges
- 20px width with a priority of 750
And the rightmost view has a 0px margin from the right edge.
All 4 views have an equal width constraint to the leftmost view. The the three buttons have margins to the two views it's between.

**4S, 5, 5S:**
[image: 4S-5 w/ Views]

**6 Plus:** (can make grey views transparent)
[image: 6 Plus w/ Views]